# less css opacity child

Tags: css, html, less, opacity

SO i started using LESS CSS. Now i have a parent div with opacity: 0.8;
I want the child to have opacity: 1;

So i created this:

```
.offerte{
    font-family: BrushScriptRegular;
    font-size: 34px;
    background-color: black;
    opacity: 0.80;

    a:hover {
    border-bottom: @underlineBorder;
    opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

I got told that this should overwrite the parents opacity in LESS. But this does not work for me. Any other solutions with LESS how to deal with this?

thx in advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12613191/why-cant-child-elements-override-the-opacity-of-parent-with-a-greater-value TLDR: use `rgba` for color and background color rather than opacity.

Comment: @steveax I know it's the best way for normal CSS. But i really thought this was possible with LESS

Comment: Nope. Ultimately LESS is gonna deliver CSS to the browser, no magic there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Their are some serious changes to your code, have a look,

```
.offerte {
    font-family: BrushScriptRegular;
    font-size: 34px;
    background-color: black;
    opacity: 0.8;
    &:hover {
    border-bottom: @underlineBorder;
    opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

I support offerte is a class of an anchor which hover down, if it is, then you should do these modifications... Thanks...