# CSS opacity 0.2 - jquery set opacity 1.0 - But 1.0 will be maximum of 0.2?

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation, opacity

Smoetimes i hate CSS and more importanly javascript (in this case, jQuery).
I've got the following:

```
#project {
    opacity: 0.2;

    float: left;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

And in my HTML i've got:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#project img').hover(function() {
        $(this).fadeTo("slow", 1);
    });
</script>

<div id="project">
    <div id="img"><img src="..."></div>
    <p>Title:</p> ...
</div>
```

But for some reason, i can't fade to `1.0` because `1.0` being the maximum value of the opacity which is set to `0.2` in my CSS file.
If i do `fadeTo("slow", 0.5);` concequently it will fade to `0.1`.

**How can i, in a simple way animate a "fade in" from a predefined `0.2` opacity to full opacity?**

Edit: The CSS part is loaded on the first page load, the HTML part is loaded via AJAX (`$("#content").load($(this).text() + ".html");`) later on.

Comment: You can't have the child (`img`) be less transparent than the parent (`#project`), if that's what you want.

Comment: You're setting `#project` to `opacity:0.2` but not the `image` opacity, so hovering on the image won't do anything.

Comment: Just figured out it. I'm trying to set the `img` opacity to `1.0` but the parent `div` is the one that has the opacity.. geez i'm stupid..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't have the child (img) be less transparent than the parent (#project), if that's what you want.

This is not jQuery or JavaScript related at all.

Comment: Yepp, you've got it :) You'll get the points as soon as i can mark it as solved. Gha been working on this for a few hours and just as i wrote the question i noticed it myself >_<

Answer (score 1):

[The opacity of a child element cannot "override" the opacity of its parent element.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12613191/why-cant-child-elements-override-the-opacity-of-parent-with-a-greater-value)

If it is feasible, you may specify your opacity for `#project` using `rgba()` colours for `color` and `background-color` properties. The alpha property is not inherited by descendent elements as opacity.

Answer (score 0):

See this Fiddle.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C6gac/1/)

It will be helpful.

To change The Css like :

```
#project img{
    opacity:0.2;

    float: left;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#project img').hover(function() {
            $(this).fadeTo("slow", 1);
        });
    });
</script>

<div id="project">
    <div id="img"><img src="..."></div>
    <p>Title:</p> ...
</div>
```

I modify your code.Now see

Answer (score 0):

try this
    #project img {
    opacity: 0.2;
    float: left;
    margin: 10px;
    }

Comment: That would some what work, but the parent div would still be opaque and that's not my goal :)