# How to exceed group opacity by an element opacity?

Tags: javascript, html, svg, dom

Do you know how to override group level opacity at the element level? For example, I would expect the following code to set rectangle opacity to 1 but it remains 0.5.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>

    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        let svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        let group= svg.append("g").attr("opacity", 0.5) // group level
        group.append("rect")
            .attr("height", 50)
            .attr("width", 50)
            .attr("opacity", 1) // element level
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

But if I interchange 0.5 and 1, it works fine!

Comment: If the parent's opacity is .5 the child's opacity will be relative to the parent's. For exemple if the child's opacity is .5 the result will be like .25 (half the opacity of the parent).

Comment: Okay, understood. Can you tell how to restore absolute opacity to 1 at the child level?

Comment: Okay, I think there is no way to do that. Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12613191/why-cant-child-elements-override-the-opacity-of-parent-with-a-greater-value/12613251

Comment: I can confirm that there is no way to do what you want.